# Javascript is targeting cached version of page in jQuery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, d3.js

New to jQuery mobile and working on an existing site using jQuery mobile rails 1.3.

The site contains a page with a section for activity within a date range and separate section with graphs using d3. The date range is set in a file report.js. The graphs are drawn in a file graph.js on `pagecreate`. The view for this page contains a div that is targeted in the javascript to draw the svgs for the graphs.

Initially when the page is loaded everything loads properly. A button is clicked and the date range is set using `$.mobile.changePage(dateString, reloadPage: true)`. This updates the activity section but the graphs no longer show up. Looking at the source another svg is added to jQuery mobile's cached version of the page. At this point the cached version contains two copies of the graphs and there is no graph on the active page. Manually reloading the page fixes everything and shows only one copy of the graph on the active page. Any ideas on what causes this and how to fix?